# Android setFullScreenIntent() execute the PendingIntent when notification reach and phone is locked

Tags: android, notifications

```
Android setFullScreenIntent() execute the PendingIntent when notification reach and phone is locked.
```

Strange issue facing when I using `setFullScreenIntent()` it will execute the `PendingIntent` which I have set as content when my phone is locked and when I unlocking my phone then app is opened. If phone is unlocked and notification received it'll be display notification as top on all screen and not execute the `PendingIntent`. Has anybody face this issue? Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Below is my code

```
Intent _intent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this,NotificationActivity.class);
_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager)GcmIntentService.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, requestCode,
                    _intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(icon)
                .setTicker(ticker)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent);

        if(CURRENT_VERSION>=LOLLIPOP_VERSION){
            builder.setColor(Color.argb(255, 117,63,0));
            builder.setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_notification_icon);
builder.setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, false);

            }
mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working on my Android 8.1.
If set the intent to null, it will become the normal notification without persist over heads-up area.

```
builder.setFullScreenIntent(null, true);
```

Comment: If you do so, the notification doesn't popup on the screen. :( I just want the notification to pop up on the screen, but not open the app on lock screen without tapping the notification.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to execute the FullScreen Intent when notification reached,just set an empty PendingIntent to FullScreen Intent.

`PendingIntent fullScreenIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GcmIntentService.this, requestCode, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setFullScreenIntent(fullScreenIntent, true);`

Comment: This should be accepted answer! Keeping FullScreenIntent required to make the notification to pop up on screen.

Answer (score -2):

Remove FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK from the intent.

`Intent _intent = new Intent(GcmIntentService.this,NotificationActivity.class);
_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);`

Comment: requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag